# How to use jquery $.post() method to submit form values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I have 1 main page with a form and another page to process the form value
here are source codes of the 2 pages

**Form Page:**

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Form Page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="process.php" method="post" id="reg-form">
        Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
        <br>
        Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" id="submit-btn">Traditional Submit</button>
        <button type="button" id="post-btn">$.Post Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    $("#post-btn").click(function(){        
        $.post("process.php",function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Process Page:**

```
<?php
$username=$_POST["username"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
echo "Username: ".$username;
echo "<br>";
echo "Password: ".$password;?>
```

if I click the "Traditional Submit" buttton, it works perfectly well.

but when I click the "$.Post Submit" button, I just keep getting error msg "Notice: Undefined Index ..."

I can not figure out where the problem is, please kindly help check and fix, thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, I'm trying to use Ajax to process the form values and stay on the main page (instead of being redirected to the process page like using the traditional form submit)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You have to select and send the form data as well:

```
$("#post-btn").click(function(){        
    $.post("process.php", $("#reg-form").serialize(), function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Take a look at the documentation for the jQuery [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize) method, which encodes the data from the form fields into a data-string to be sent to the server.

Comment: Just adding to this: `action="process.php" method="post"` is no longer needed on the `<form>` element as the submission is being handled by the jQuery AJAX `.post()` method.

Answer (score 9):

Get the value of your textboxes using `val()` and store them in a variable. Pass those values through `$.post`. In using the `$.Post Submit button` you can actually remove the form.

```
<script>

    username = $("#username").val(); 
    password = $("#password").val();

    $("#post-btn").click(function(){        
        $.post("process.php", { username:username, password:password } ,function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Even better, use the [`serialize` method](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: @SeanVieira I don't know how to use that. What's the purpose of it? I've been learning that but just can't understand :) Please tell me

Comment: `serialize` takes a form (or a set of inputs) and turns all of the `input`, `select`, and `textarea` tags into a string suitable for sending as the body of an HTTP POST request (or as the query string of a GET request).  For example, serializing a form with the single field, `<input name="firstName" value="Sean">` becomes `"firstName=Sean"`.

Comment: @SeanVieira ok thanks and then you just need to post or get the firstName? :)

Comment: Yes - then you can directly use that string in `$.ajax` or any of its cousins (`$.post`, `$.get`), as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25881249/135978) does

Answer (score 7):

Yor `$.post` has no data. You need to pass the form data. You can use `serialize()` to post the form data. Try this

```
$("#post-btn").click(function(){
    $.post("process.php", $('#reg-form').serialize() ,function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
});
```