# Changing 'width' of the progress bar in CSS with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am learning JQuery and I think I have failed to understand some basics. I am trying to change the width of the progress bar (as if it is moving) to +2% every time one of the radio buttons is clicked. But my function is wrong (value + 2). I would appreciate any comments about that. And when I change it to some fixed value it does not really stay like that. I guess the 'change method' initializes the whole thing every time. So my question is what is the best way to write the result into a file (what I do with 'submit' now) and increase the 'width' value of the progress bar at the same time? Any comment is very appreciated.

```
<html>
<style>
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#progressbar {
  width: 2%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #1D1387;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
</style>
    <head>
        <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script>  
 $(document).ready(function() {   
   $('input[name=score]').change(function(){  
        $('form').submit();
        <!-- progress bar moves on 2% every time the radio button is clicked (form is submitted)-->
        $('#progressbar').css('width', function(index, value){
        return value + 2;
        });
   });  
  });  
</script>
    </head>

<form>
<p>Please select one of the variants below:</p><br />
<h2>word</h2>
<br />
<input type="hidden" name="word" value="{{ word }}"/><br />
<label class="rad"><input type="radio" name="score" value="var1" />variant1</label>
<label class="rad"><input type="radio" name="score" value="var2" />variant2</label>
<label class="rad"><input type="radio" name="score" value="var3" />variant3</label>
<label class="rad_other"><input type="radio" name="score" value="var4" />variant4</label><br />
<br />
</form>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="progressbar">0/50</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After the form "submit" the page usually being reloaded and scripts loads again (if it's not Ajax) - this could be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you submit your form, then you are loading a new page (even if it is the same page) and losing the progress bar changes.

Your code works if you remove the `submit()` and change the way you increment the width like so:

```
$('input[name=score]').change(function(){
    $('#progressbar').css('width', function(index, value){
        return "+=2%";
    });
});
```

A solution for your requests is to use some Ajax and do a POST request (see [jQuery post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)). There is a question on SO where you can find ways to do this: [How to use jquery $.post() method to submit form values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881204/how-to-use-jquery-post-method-to-submit-form-values)

An other solution would be to set the progress bar width when you generate your page (with your back-end language) and keep track of this progress with each requests.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're using an HTML comment (`<!-- -->`) in JavaScript, which uses `//` or `/* ... */` comments.

Second, reading the documentation for `css(...)` you'll see that the value provided to the function might not be in the same unit as in the stylesheet. Putting a simple `console.log(value)` in the function, we see that it gets the value in pixels.

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/wurtj7Le/8/). I changed the comment and put the percentage in a variable. I had to remove the `form.submit()` to get the JSFiddle to work, but you can keep it.