# POST Method not working in Spring MVC

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc

I have created a login form

```
<form class="login100-form validate-form p-b-33 p-t-5" method="POST">
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username">
    <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="User name">
    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xe82a;"></span>
</div>
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
    <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xe80f;"></span>
</div>
<div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-32">
    <input class="login100-form-btn" type="button" onclick="location.href='eLibrary/login'" value="Login" >
</div>
```

And my controller function is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String userName = request.getParameter("username");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    return "list-books";
}
```

But, when I'm trying to login, it's giving error

> HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed
>
> Request method 'GET' not supported

I even have tried

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public String login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String userName = request.getParameter("username");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    return "list-books";
}
```

But in the above case, request.getParameter("username") is giving null.

Can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the line:

```
<input class="login100-form-btn" type="button" onclick="location.href='eLibrary/login'" value="Login" >
```

with remove the onclick:

```
<input class="login100-form-btn" type="submit" value="Login" >
```

and update the FORM line to:

```
<form class="login100-form validate-form p-b-33 p-t-5" method="POST" action="eLibrary/login">
```

Onclick will always send a GET request. If you wanna do POST with javascript you have to use AJAX action.

Comment: then how do you suggest me to handle the onclick part.?

Comment: You have two choices: 1. Remove onclick and do standard POST action. 2: Use javascript xHttpRequest or one of the framework (eg. jQuery) to send post action. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881204/how-to-use-jquery-post-method-to-submit-form-values

Answer (score 0):

Update below line

```
<input class="login100-form-btn" type="button" onclick="location.href='eLibrary/login'" value="Login" >
```

with `<input class="login100-form-btn" type="submit" onclick="location.href='eLibrary/login'" value="Login" >`

Comment: It's not giving any error now, but redirecting me to the same login page and not even going to the break-point when running in debug mode.

Comment: try writing `return "/list-books"`

Comment: In my sevlet.xml I already have
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
 <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
 <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

So, "/" will automatically be prefixed

Comment: what url is updated while clicking on submit button?

Comment: url is not changing, it seems it just is refreshing the page
And when I'm simply clicking on "Login" button(without entering any data) then same Error-405 is coming

Comment: remove `onclick` from `<input>` tag and add `action="eLibrary/login"` in form tag